# No write permission when inserting data to TDengine

Tags: java, database, tdengine

1. I'm using JDBC to read/write data from/to TDengine database. Linux server.
   When executing insert statement, I got an error report.

Cause: java.sql.SQLException: TDengine ERROR (80000214): No write permission

I googled the error message, but got no help. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According its document, you can grant read or write permissions.

If the version you use is below 3.0, you can try:

```
ALTER USER <user_name> PRIVILEGE <write|read>;
```

If the version you use is 3.0, you can try:

```
GRANT privileges ON priv_level TO user_name


privileges : {
    ALL
  | priv_type [, priv_type] ...
}
 
priv_type : {
    READ
  | WRITE
}
 
priv_level : {
    dbname.*
  | *.*
}
```